# How to perform .replace() function on list, if list contains strings, integers and/or floats?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, replace

Imagine I have a list as such:

```
mylist = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '#N/A', '#N/A', '#N/A', '#N/A', None, None, None, '#N/A', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Now I want to replace all #N/A's with None, and am able to do so with the code below:

```
#Here we have to say *item and* otherwise it will return:
#AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
[item and item.replace("#N/A", "None") for item in mylist]
#prints
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', None, None, None, 'None', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

However, when the list contains integers, I can't perform this operation anymore, and do not know how to elegantly solve this problem?

```
mylist = ['xxx', None, 'x', 'x', None, 'Pv', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, '00000001', '#N/A', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'Suc', 171.1, 'na', 'na', 
6, None, 'H(1970)']
[item and item.replace("#N/A", "None") for item in mylist]
#prints
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <listcomp>
**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'**
```

For any bonus points, I also can't convert string to None with replace function:

```
[item and item.replace("#N/A", None) for item in mylist]
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not None
```

Comment: .replace() is a string method; what you want can be achieved via list comprehension: for example for your last point: output  = [None if i == '#N/A' else i for i in mylist]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
newlist = [None if item == '#N/A' else item for item in mylist]
```

That will work regardless of the data types contained in your list.

Given:

```
mylist = [
    "xxx",
    None,
    "x",
    "x",
    None,
    "Pv",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    "00000001",
    "#N/A",
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "Suc",
    171.1,
    "na",
    "na",
    6,
    None,
    "H(1970)",
]
```

The above code produces:

```
[
    "xxx",
    None,
    "x",
    "x",
    None,
    "Pv",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    "00000001",
    None,
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "na",
    "Suc",
    171.1,
    "na",
    "na",
    6,
    None,
    "H(1970)",
]
```

(If you intended all those `na` values to be `#N/A` then of course they would end up as `None` in the result.)

Comment: Thank you. My list comprehension isn't that strong. Beautiful solution.

Comment: List comprehension (which extends to tuples and dicts btw) is powerful and has a very intuitive syntax, so be sure to work on it. Also, don't forget to mark larsks' answer as accepted.

Comment: I did found myself to have to also remove the "na" strings as well, so applied ```[None if (item == '#N/A' or item == "na") else item for item in mylist]```.